# Hibernate: Able to load entity but cannot save. Unknown Entity exception is being thrown back

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, save, pojo

I am noticing a strange issue. I have an hibernate mapping file associated with an entity class.

I am able to load the entity from the database via following way:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forEntityName(entityName);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in(CAMPAIGN_ID, campaignIds));
itemsFromDB = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
```

I am able to get the items from the database. Entity name is defined in the hibernate mapping file. Hibernate is able to return instances of the associated entity class (defined in the mapping file) with data loaded from the database.

However, I am not able to save new entities. I am trying to save entities in a transaction (using @Transactional annotation). I get following exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: abc.com.MyClass
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:580)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1365)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:550)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:546)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:693)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
```

I would really appreciate if anybody can provide any information.

Thanks

Comment: Abhishek : can you give your hibernate.cfg.xml mapping file?

Comment: how do you save? did you specify the entityname there?

Comment: @Firo I did not specify the entity name while saving. I am saving it using the hibernate template. getHibernateTemplate().save(ruleEntity)

Comment: hibernate needs to know which entityname the object belongs to to get the mapping. You have to specify it somehow in the hibernateTemplate or go get the underlying hibernate session